# How to get numbering to flow properly in Table of Contents

Tags: syntax

Could someone tell me why the following code isn't numbering properly? I'm following the instructions from http://jsfiddle.net/N79nP/ however the numbering doesn't continue past 1. I'm very new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <ol class="inhoudsopgave">
    <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <ol class="inhoudsopgave">
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#</a></li>
        <ol class="inhoudsopgave">
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#</a>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ol>
    </ol>   
    <ol class="inhoudsopgave">
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <ol class="inhoudsopgave">
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ol>
    </ol>   
    <ol class="inhoudsopgave">      
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <ol class="inhoudsopgave">
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ol>
    </ol>   
    <ol class="inhoudsopgave">  
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <ol class="inhoudsopgave">
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
</ol>
```

Comment: you are closing the first `li` tag before opening the first (supposedly nested?) `ol`. this is in fact invalid html. what exactly are you trying to accomplish? could you provide a small example?

Comment: I'm trying to get the following hierarchy: a list with 3 levels of depth i.e. 1 -> 1.1 -> 1.1.1 and 2 -> 2.1 -> 2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, your list is a mess.  You are nesting your OLs inside OLs.  If you want to have a list with sub lists, the heiarchy should look like this.

```
<ol class="inhoudsopgave">
    <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a>
    <ol class="inhoudsopgave">
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a>
    <ol class="inhoudsopgave">
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="inhoudsopgave"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: On the same note, how does the hierarchy look when the list has 1 more level of depth i.e. 1 -> 1.1 -> 1.1.1 and 2 -> 2.1 -> 2.1.1

Comment: It doesn't do anything other than putting in another ordered list (OL).  A good practice is to switch to letters on the tertiary.  You can specify that in your CSS by defining it in the class.

Comment: What would the CSS look like for that?

Comment: You really don't even NEED to put it in CSS.  It's just a better practice.  You can simply add it to your OL tag, like this:   <ol type="a">  That will order your list starting with the letter "a".